# PHP extracting values from array and restoring them into another array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have an Array of values pulled from a mysql table of the form:

```
$name_ids = EMP-646
            EMP-545
            EMP-12
            CLIENT-36
            CLIENT-43
            CLIENT-5
```

I would like to identify EMP and CLIENT as separate data and then extract only the integer values and then store them into separate variables. For example:

```
$emp_id =    646
             545
             12

$client_id = 36
             43 
             5
```

Here is my attempt at it but I am unable to print the desired results (not sure if my logic is correct):

```
$name_ids = array($_SESSION['INVITED_NAMES']);

foreach($name_ids[0] as $name_id){
  if(stripos($name_id, 'EMP') !== false){ 
    $emp_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$name_id);
  }
  elseif(stripos($name_id, 'CLIENT') !== false){ 
    $client_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$name_id);
  }

  echo $emp_id.' '; //both results need to happen at this stage in the `foreach` loop.
  echo $client_id.' ';              
}
```

One thing to note is I need the results to appear where they are due to other code that is dependent on this location. With the present code this is the results I get:

```
646 545 12 36 12 43 12 5 12
```

The error appears at the first if statement(`$emp_id`), when a value is false it returns the last int of a true value until the loop is through.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is working: https://eval.in/84445

Relevant code:

```
$emp_ids = array();
$client_ids = array();

$name_ids = array('EMP-646',
            'EMP-545',
            'EMP-12',
            'CLIENT-36',
            'CLIENT-43',
            'CLIENT-5');

var_dump($name_ids);            

foreach($name_ids as $name_id){
  if(stripos($name_id, 'EMP') !== false){ 
    $emp_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$name_id);
    array_push($emp_ids, $emp_id);
  }
  elseif(stripos($name_id, 'CLIENT') !== false){ 
    $client_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$name_id);
    array_push($client_ids, $client_id);
  }

}

echo "Emp_ids are: ";
var_dump($emp_ids);

echo "Client_ids are: ";
var_dump($client_ids);
```

I just created arrays to store the values, and pushed them in.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution is essentially what I asked for. However, it is not the results I am looking for. It is my fault for not explaining more specifically the results I need. The output data cannot be saved into an array because I am inserting the data into a table and each value needs to be inserted separately.  That is why I need to keep the 2 variables within the foreach loop.  maybe it is not possible to do what I am looking for.

Comment: Once you have them in 2 sep arrays, you can do pretty much whatever you want with them. I saw that comment in your post, and you can't get 2 values foreach... think about it. The first time you go through the loop, the value is `'EMP-646'`  so how could there be a CLIENT value?

Comment: If you need the values paired, you just create a new $i loop and use $emp_ids[$i], $client_ids[$i].

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean. I'll just have to go back to the drawing board with this one.

Comment: You're very close... maybe submit a new question related to your arrays and how you need to insert them.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer since it did answer the question.  I end up figuring out the solution I was looking for using the function `array_unique` on the output data. Thanks again